# The program takes up a lot of RAM, when the button is pressed (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have animations made in my program and when I hover over the button, the picture changes and there are a lot of such buttons, but when you hover over several buttons, the program starts to take up a lot of RAM, here's the code how the pictures change, is there another option?

```
private void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logoVkDdos1.Image = Image.FromFile("F:\\.аZullanEasy\\c#\\1\\yt_DesignUI\\Resources\\vkLogoDefault.png");
    }
```

Comment: You need to dispose of the previous image before loading a new one. Add `if (logoVkDdos1.Image != null) logoVkDdos1.Image.Dispose();` before that line.

Comment: Don't keep creating new `Image` objects from the same file over and over. Create the `Image` once and then use it repeatedly. Why would you be surprised that creating lots of images consumes lots of memory?

Comment: When dealing with mouse events, you need to write your logic so that it doesn't duplicate work already done. Because a mouse can emit a lot of events. For example, you could move the `Image.FromFile` call to the form load event and cache it. Then you'd just need to set a reference to it in the mouse event(s).